# .NET Core sanity check asynchronous tasks and having to wait for them all the complete

Tags: .net-core, async-await

I have a bunch of remote http calls to make and I need to fire them off in parallel but wait for them all to complete before I can continue processing. This is an ASP.NET Core MVC website, so I am happy that when I am waiting the server is doing something else.

These http calls are using `PostAsJsonAsync` on an http client, so they are async anyway.

Is the correct approach a `List<Task>` and each task having the http request in and then doing a `listoftasts.WaitAll()` or am I missing something painfully obvious. There is `listoftasks.WhenAll()` as well. But I need execution of the thread to not continue because what happens is dependent on the results of the operations.

I find that docs change and this is 2022 question and dot net sometimes does things differently. Plus the fact that the `PostAsJsonAsync` is an async operation anyway may change things.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: To me WaitAll() on your list of Task seems to be the correct approach.

Comment: `WhenAll` is the async version of `WaitAll` - using `WaitAll` basically "destroys" any benefit the `PostAsJsonAsync` might have had - use `WhenAll` to keep that async "groove" going :-)

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(bunchOfTasks);` will await for those tasks without blocking. `WaitAll` will block the request thread, preventing it from serving some other request while waiting for those tasks to complete.